# C# Action, Func , Can be Nested or Chaining?

Tags: delegates, action, func

I am Novice in Delegate (in English too).

This is my sample code:

```
var expected_for = new int[Length];

Func<int[], Action<int>> opFactory = res => i => res[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i];

Parallel.For(0, arg1.Length, opFactory(expected)); // working well

Enumerable.Range(0, arg1.Length).ToList().ForEach(opFactory(expected_foreach));  // working well

         for (int i = 0; i < arg1.Length; i++)
            {
                opFactory(expected_for); //No Error, but expected_for is not changed
            }
```

Q1. `Func<int[], Action<int>> opFactory = res => i => res[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i];`
   in `Func`, `Action` can be nested? This is too difficult to understand for me.

Q2. `Parallel.For`'s third argument requires `Action`. Then my `Func` Line was `Action`?

Q3. How can I save value in `for()`?

Thank you for reading

Regards

ICE

Comment: about Q3, I found the solution "opFactory(expected_for)(i)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates are simpler than you think.
Let's take Func.The last argument is the result that must be returned.
So you need to specify at least one generic parameter
For examaple `Func<int,string>` can point do any methods that accept an int and return a string 
In the following example all 4 funcs do the same thing.

Q1:You can make them as complex as you want.
Q2:No Action is not the same a Func.It works because the is an overload that accepts a Func
Q3:It didn't work because without the (i) you don't actually call the method.You called opFactory and ignored its result

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ///lamda statement
            Func<int, string> func4 = i => { return i.ToString(); };

            ///lamda expression (if there is only 1 statement)
            Func<int, string> func3 = i => i.ToString();

            Func<int, string> func2 = delegate (int i) { return i.ToString(); };

            //Just point to an existing method
            Func<int, string> func1 = ToString;
        }

        static string ToString(int arg)
        {
            return arg.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And a full example

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Length = 5;

            var arg1 = Enumerable.Range(10, Length).ToArray();
            var arg2 = Enumerable.Range(100, Length).ToArray();

            var expected = new int[Length];
            var expected_for = new int[Length];
            var expected_foreach = new int[Length];

            Func<int[], Action<int>> opFactory = res => i => res[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i];

            Parallel.For(0, arg1.Length, opFactory(expected));

            Enumerable.Range(0, arg1.Length).ToList().ForEach(opFactory(expected_foreach));

            for (int i = 0; i < arg1.Length; i++)
            {
                opFactory(expected_for)(i);
            }

            //all 3 tables have the same data 110,112,114,116,118
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really Perfect Answer for me. Thank you  very much